# Grouping issue on a content query

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, grouping

I have created a content query pulling in a summary of the page library content. When I group the content based on “Topic”, I get the correct result for how I want the page organised, however all the text overlaps (see screenshot). If I take the grouping off, the overlap disappears but then the content is quite hard to sort through. Any suggestions on how I can get rid of the overlap? Thanks!

[image: Content query screenshot]

Comment: Is this the same after stopping editing, in all browsers? Open develop mode of browser (F12) and look at CSS? May be some little change will help you.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I found a script box that was forcing the columns into this format, I have removed this and the overlap has been fixed.

Comment: Is this a built-in script? Please, post your receipt as an answer.

Comment: Or even write to MS support.